# Common practice deploying/publish/debuggin a java webapp

Tags: java, eclipse

I have always programmed my applications in php. But recenlty I discovered that best combination of language and server to achieve scalable comet functionality is Java + Jetty, because jetty support continuation, which eases the number of threads in the server. However, I'm slowly learning Java right now. I'm using Eclipse as my IDE with the plugin RSE(Remote System Explorer). When I used to program in PHP I just created a new php-file inside of htdocs in my Apache webserver, very simple to deploy. But now when I program in Java I have to compile the file too. Another flaw is that I cant create a Dynamic web project in RSE, so to deploy a webapp I have to drag all my file in my personal computer to my remote server and unzip and compile(manually via ssh). How do you guys deploy your java webapp in Eclipse?

And yes I haven't found any good answer to this on the web yet before asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install a web server on your machine, and do all your development and tests locally on your machine. When the application is ready, deploy it on your remote server.

You don't have to compile it on the server. Java bytecode is portable across OSes and machines. You can build your war file on your machine and send it to the remote server.

Comment: Do you know how to creata war files for jetty? I can only see tutorials for Tomcat so far. like this one http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-make-war-file-in-eclipse.html But I don't have the tomcat tab in my properties window?